# Try to make in http interceptor which redirect to login page on 403 error

Tags: angular

I try to make an http interceptor which redirect to the login page if an 401 or 403 error append. No problem for the interceptor but when I do the "router.navigate" I have an error : "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined".

My http interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectHttp extends Http {
constructor(protected backend: ConnectionBackend, protected defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private router: Router, private loginUrl: string) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
}

...

intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch(this.handleError) as Observable<Response>;
}

private handleError(error: any): any {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403 && !error.url.endsWith("/" + this.loginUrl)) {
        this.router.navigate([this.loginUrl]);
        return Observable.empty();
    } else {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

}
```

}

The declaration on application.Module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    entryComponents: [...],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders,
        {provide: Http,
            useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new RedirectHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, LOGIN.path),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ApplicationApp]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I think there is a mistake with the Router injection, but I don't find where.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only thing that helped me in redirect was:

```
intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigate([this.loginUrl]);
        }
        return this.handleError(error);
    });
}
```